# Firebase уведомления.(Android)

Tags: android, firebase, уведомления

Здравствуйте, в моем приложении я использую FireBase DataBase.
В моем приложении можно сделать заказ. Заказ формируется и отправляется в базу данных на сервис. есть поле даты отправки. Мне нужно что-бы через 5 минут от даты отправки приходило уведомление на два конкретных телефона. Умею пользоваться FireBase уведомлениями, но отправлять уведомления могу только с консоли. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

используйте `Firebase Notifications` 
[Send a Notification to an Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device)